# Updating single item in a basket with multiple items using php and My Sql

Tags: php

I am making a shopping basket for my website and I am stuck on updating the quantities, I have a database conected and the basket is being generated from a basket table, I have a Loop which displays the products in a users basket and produces a 
form for each product that is generating a textbox where a user can enter the quanitity and then click submit. I have a seperate file called updatebasket which excutes an UPDATE statement using the gameID in the whereclause. I am having trouble sending the gameID for each product over to the updatebasket file when the update button is clicked. Here is my code below.

**This is the cart.php File**

```
CART.PHP
<?php
require "dbconnect.php";
session_start();
$memberID = $_SESSION['id']; 

$query = "SELECT rectable.gameID, rectable.gameIMG, rectable.gamePrice, rectable.gameName FROM rectable, basket WHERE rectable.gameID = basket.gameID AND basket.id = '".$memberID."'";

$results = $connect->query($query);
$numrow = $results->num_rows;

$count = 0;
while ($count < $numrow)
{
$row = $results -> fetch_assoc();
extract($row);
echo"<div>";
echo"<div class='recommended_games'>";
    echo "<img src='images/".$gameIMG."' />";
echo "</div>";


echo '<div class="price_tag">';
    echo '<div class="price_tag">£'.$gamePrice. '</div>';
echo'</div>';

echo '<div id="update_form"><form action="updatebasket.php" method="post" name="updateform">';
echo  '<input type="text" value="1" name="quantity" id="quantity" />';
echo '<input type="text" value="'.$gameID.'" name="'.$gameID.'" id="gameid" />';
echo    '<input type="submit" value="update" />';
echo '</form>';
echo '</div>';                                            

echo"<img class='box1' src='Images/Grey-Banners.png' />";
echo"</div>";
$count = $count + 1;        
}        
?>
```

**This is the updatebasket.php file**

```
UPDATEBASKET.PHP
<?php
session_start();
require "dbconnect.php";

$memberID = $_SESSION['id']; 

$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
$gameID = $_POST['gameID'];

$query = "UPDATE basket SET quantity = '".$quantity."' WHERE gameID = '".$gameID."' AND id = '".$memberID."' ";
header('Location: cart.php')
?>
```

Comment: because your gameID is array

Comment: i tried to take it out of an array but nothing changed if possible could you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: can you try to put "name='{$gameid[]}' inside your html? and call at updatebasket.php with foreach loop.